# Pinch ZoomIn/ZoomOut effect on Image using JqueryMobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, pinchzoom

I have to add functionality of Pinch ZoomIn/Out effect on image using jqueryMobile Plugin, can any one help?

Thanks alot,

--Brock

Answer (score 6):

It is possible on jQuery Mobile, but you will need to use a 3rd party implementation called [**hammer.js**](https://github.com/EightMedia/hammer.js/wiki/Getting-Started).

It supports a large number of gestures like:

- hold
- tap
- doubletap
- drag, dragstart, dragend, dragup, dragdown, dragleft, dragright
- swipe, swipeup, swipedown, swipeleft, swiperight
- transform, transformstart, transformend
- rotate
- pinch, pinchin, pinchout
- touch (gesture detection starts)
- release (gesture detection ends)

Example:

```
$('#test_el').hammer().on("pinchin", ".nested_el", function(event) {
    console.log(this, event);
});

$('#test_el').hammer().on("pinchout", ".nested_el", function(event) {
    console.log(this, event);
});
```

It works with jQuery Mobile, and that is important. But you should think of some other idea, or at least another idea for Android 2.X devices, because that platform doesn't support multitouch events.

There are also some other 3rd party implementations, like [**Touchy**](https://github.com/HotStudio/touchy). Unfortunately, Touchy only supports pinch.

Comment: Gajotres thanks for your kind reply my scenario is hybrid not platform dependent. so do you thing that Touchy would be applicable for iphone and andorid devices?thanks,