# How to zoom in and zoom out using swiping fingers in jquery mobile.?

Tags: jquery-mobile

Can you please tell me is there any way to zoom in or zoom out using swiping finger .As we do in Android /Iphone the screen will zoom in and zoom out when we swipe finger on 
screen .I check lot of event like scrollstart, swipe.I don't know which method will used to check it's length is increase or decrease.
can we used touchstart or startmove function?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

don't you mean pinch (pinch in / pinch out) rather than swipe?

If so, see the following:

[Pinch ZoomIn/ZoomOut effect on Image using JqueryMobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16424686/pinch-zoomin-zoomout-effect-on-image-using-jquerymobile)

Comment: I need to zoom screen not image